# Simple user request for filename for output and input

Tags: c++, filenames, istream

How can I request the user to input the filename that my program needs to read from and have it output the name with `.out` extension instead?

Example:

```
char fileName[256];
cout << "What is the file name that should be processed?";
cin >> fileName;

inFile.open(fileName);
outFile.open(fileName);
```

But I need it to save the file as a filename.out instead of the original document type (IE:.txt)

I've tried this:

```
char fileName[256];
cout << "What is the file name that should be processed?";
cin >> fileName;

inFile.open(fileName.txt);
outFile.open(fileName.out);
```

But I get these errors:

> c:\users\matt\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\dspi\dspi\dspi.cpp(41) : error C2228: left of '.txt' must have class/struct/union
>   1>        type is 'char [256]'
>
> c:\users\matt\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\dspi\dspi\dspi.cpp(42) : error C2228: left of '.out' must have class/struct/union
>   1>        type is 'char [256]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change fileName extension:

```
string fileName;
cin >> fileName;
string newFileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.find_last_of('.')) + ".out";
```

Comment: Try testing with a file name like 'x.y.z', or path like: "abc.def\xyz\file.txt".

Comment: That was supposed to be find_last_of, not find_first_of :) Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are using iostreams, implying the use of C++. That in turn means you should probably be using std::string, which has overloaded operators for string concatenation - and the nice side effect of automatic memory management and added security.

```
#include <string>
// ...
// ...
std::string input_filename;
std::cout << "What is the file name that should be processed?\n";
std::cin >> input_filename;
// ...
infile.open(input_filename + ".txt");
```

Comment: I tried that but got an error. Looked it up and .open doesn't take string as an argument. But I found a line of code that makes it so.   inFile.open(inputFile.c_str(), ios::in);
    outFile.open(outputFile.c_str(), ios::in);

Answer (score 0):

Writing `filename.txt` implies that `fileName` is an object and you want to access it's data member `.txt`. (Similar argument applies to `fileName.out`). Instead, use

```
inFile.open(fileName + ".txt");
outFile.open(fileName + ".out");
```

Comment: Yeah, now that i think about it that makes perfect logical sense!